How to get method tips？
I am wrapping the create function of zustand, but I have a problem, I can not get the methods prompt through get() when using, does anyone know how to deal with it?
function create<T, M>(
  state: T,
  methods: (set: (s: T) => void, get: () => T & M) => M
): T & M {
  const m = methods(
    (_state) => void 0,
    () => ({ ...state, ...m })
  );
  return {
    ...state,
    ...m,
  }
}

const store = create({ a: 1, count: 10 }, (set, get) => ({
  test() {
    get() // Expected: prompt the test, test2 methods
  },
  test2() {
  }
}));


Expected: prompt the test, test2 methods
Actual: only have state prompts
